# Which filter/action hook gets triggered after a query has been performed?

Tags: wp-query, filters, actions

Is there an action or filter that gets called after an instance of WP_Query performs a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, `the_posts` gets called just after the posts have been selected from the database and it passes an array of `$posts` as a first parameter and the `$wp_query` object as second parameter to your hooked function.